# Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview health Emergency

Tags: react-native, build.gradle

android studio keeps giving this error during build.
I tried to follow other guides but all the solutions do not give the desired result.
This is the full error:

```
"Duplicate class com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-10e7b4da8b-runtime (com.github.adityaxjha:Android-ScalableVideoView:10e7b4da8b) and jetified-Android-ScalableVideoView-v1.0.4-jitpack-runtime (com.github.MatrixFrog:Android-ScalableVideoView:v1.0.4-jitpack)".
```

I tried to downgrade react-video version from 5.2.1 to 5.1.1, but making this change from this error: `com.yqritc.scalablevideoview not found`.
to find the not found mentioned above the guides say to use the `jcenter()` but it is deprecated and they advised to put the `mavenCentral()` which I already had inside the code but there too no change.

100% sure I'm doing something wrong but I know what,
i also invalidated the cache and rebuild but no change.

I'm not sure what to show you as code to better understand where the problem might be, do you want the gradle? or something else?

i believe in you
Thanks in advance

i work with react-native version 0.70.6,
this is the android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
        kotlinVersion = '1.6.10'
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "19.2.0"
        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
    }
```

if you need anything else to help me let me know because i don't know how to go on.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
        kotlinVersion = '1.6.10'
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "19.2.0"
        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.0.1")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```